Utilize order of table in PostgreSQL query to count timeranges containing each time
I have a table logs_bl_sj, which is ordered by startdate:



bundesland
startdate
enddate




'Hessen'
2015-02-26 16:22:21
2015-02-26 16:31:31


'Hessen'
2015-10-20 22:34:54
2015-10-20 22:35:03


'Bremen'
2015-10-20 22:35:50
2015-10-20 22:37:03


...





I want to find for each row r, how many rows x exist in this table where:
x.startdate <= r.startdate and r.startdate < x.enddate and r.bundesland = x.bundesland
In other words, for each startdate s, I want to find the number of timeranges [a, b) containing s with the same value for bundesland (which is always at least one: s is always contained in [s, b)).
Notice how useful the order of the table is: for each row, rows that come after this row will not count and so should not even be checked.
How can I make use of this fact through PostgreSQL? i.e. how can I make the server ignore all rows after each row when calculating for that row?
I am close to a query that gets the right data, however it is without the above mentioned optimization. Here's what I have:
SELECT bundesland, startdate, COUNT(time_range) FILTER (WHERE time_range @> startdate::timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY bundesland)
FROM logs_bl_sj_timerange

where logs_bl_sj_timerange is logs_bl_sj from above, but with an added column time_range that is just tsrange with [startdate, enddate).
The COUNT just returns the number of time_ranges in the bundesland... I expected the number of time ranges in that bundesland which contain startdate.
Bonus question: Would it be better to do this procedurally e.g. in Python? Iterating over the ordered startdates, one could keep a running count that changes based on a stored array of enddates... whereas PostgreSQL will have to start a fresh count for each row...

"In other words, for each startdate s, I want to find the number of timeranges [a, b) containing s with the same value". But you do realize you'll get the same data with ~r - 1 count, right? If in your example Hessen had 10 entries between 16 and 22 o'clock, the last one would get around 9 (excluding the enddate clause), while the fourth would probably have 2 or 3, but the end result would be maybe 9 analyses of Hessen (again, excluding the enddate). So wouldn't it make more sense to get the most recent timestamp for each bundesland and see how many are lower than that using your clauses?

I'm confused by this @TheNomad. "same data" but later "around 9" and "maybe 9"...
What is meant by "most recent timestamp"? MAX(startdate) or is this meant in a recursive way i.e. for each row?

Yes, I meant like a MAX(startdate) per bundesland. It just seems simpler to always focus on the latest snapshot and apply the filtering on that, instead of a recursive filtering starting with the oldest which would already be included in the MAX() one, right? Unless I misunderstood your request, in which case, I apologize.

You can do that with a self-join (assuming id primary key, to shorten the group by). Each row will join to itself as well as any other row from the same bundesland that has a matching time_range: Demo at db<>fiddle:
select a.*,count(*)
from logs_bl_sj_timerange a
join logs_bl_sj_timerange b 
  on a.bundesland=b.bundesland
 and b.time_range @> a.startdate
group by a.id;

Correlated scalar subquery, which is pretty much equivalent to Cetin Basoz' idea: from each row it looks around at other rows in the same bundesland and counts them based on their time_range match.
select *,(select count(*)
          from logs_bl_sj_timerange s2
          where s1.bundesland = s2.bundesland
            and s1.startdate >= s2.startdate
            and s1.startdate < s2.enddate)
from logs_bl_sj_timerange s1


Some remarks:



I have a table logs_bl_sj, which is ordered by startdate:


Notice how useful the order of the table is: for each row, rows that come after this row will not count and so should not even be checked.

Unless you select things and add an order by clause, the concept of table order does not apply. The table can be physically written in some order and you can force that by setting up an index and asking the db to cluster the table by it, but unless you add an order by to a select, PostgreSQL neither guarantees any row order, nor does it even have to consider it for any operation.
If you observed some pattern in how the table seems to be accessed, you can't rely on that. At any point, the db is free to reorder the tuples, it's always free to read them any way it wants, and reorder them throughout an execution of a query, as many times as it finds it useful.

The time_range @> startdate condition in your aggregate/window filter clause refers to values from the exact same row, the one currently considered by count(), making it always true. Your idea would've worked if startdate somewhow came from your current row in the context of the outer query, while time_range was the one taken from other rows in the window frame.
Notice how there's no such distinction available in there, as to which is which, which gives you a hint it doesn't work like that because without that distinction, there's no way for it to work like that.



Would it be better to do this procedurally e.g. in Python? Iterating over the ordered startdates, one could keep a running count that changes based on a stored array of enddates... whereas PostgreSQL will have to start a fresh count for each row...

It would not. If you really don't want to trust PostgreSQL planner/optimizer and force a certain way of collecting the results, you have recursive CTE's. You can also resort toPL/pgSQL and there's even PL/Python, without taking one step off the db. I don't even think you need any of these, let alone manually typing out imperatively how to arrive at a result that you can tell the db declaratively, to just give to you, and let it come up with an optimal way of creating, accessing and processing all relevant data structures.
Dismissing what the database planner/optimizer offers and handling things imperatively is not unlike dismissing a compiler and writing your own lower-level code instead. It does sometimes make sense, but it's best to first really make sure it does, and I don't think it's one of those cases. There's a ton of stuff the db does automagically, that you'd have to re-implement to get close to its performance and reliability.



Thank you! I'm new to relational databases and your remarks are highly appreciated. When I have enough reputation to vote this up, I will lol

There are multiple ways to solve this and using lateral is one of them. Its effectiveness depends on the data (how selective given a bundesland + startdate combination is):
select *
from sampleData s1,
     lateral (select count(*)
              from sampleData s2
              where s1.bundesland = s2.bundesland
                and s1.startdate >= s2.startdate
                and s1.startdate < s2.enddate) as cnt;

As per the bonus question, I don't think Python would be faster. You can try it yourself on a large data set. And if you have a large data set, doing this with some extension might be much better (ie: timescaledb).
DBFiddle demo
EDIT: Note that postgreSQL would utilize an index on startDate pretty well.
